# How to call Datatables API functions in Rails CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, datatables, jquery-datatables-rails

I simply wish to call a function called `fnGetNodes()` to get an array of all nodes. 
(source of data-tables functions to calls: http://datatables.net/api)

I have set up as:

```
# DataTable
  table = $("#restaurantLocations").DataTable()

# Selecting all
  $("#selectAllLocations").click ->
    rows = table.fnGetNodes()
```

Yet as I refresh and click the button `Select All` I receive the following error on the line `table.fnGetNodes()`:

[image]

It should be very easy, but how can I call functions on datatables in CoffeeScript?

Comment: What is `table` after you refresh? Is `table` what you expect it to be inside the callback? Is `table` in scope when you define that callback? Are you saying `$x.DataTable()` or `$x.dataTable()`?

Comment: I'm using .DataTable(), add seen in the code

Comment: Got it to work with replacing `table.fnGetNodes()` with `$("#restaurantLocations").dataTable().fnGetNodes()`

Comment: So it was just a typo in `table = $("#restaurantLocations").DataTable()` that should have been `table = $("#restaurantLocations").dataTable()` then?

Comment: No, some functions need .dataTable() and others .DataTable, so I just call an instance of `$("#restaurantLocations").dataTable()` on those other functions

Comment: How can I call `.toggleClass "selected"` on all the none filtered columns?

Comment: No this did not wok, I cant call anything

Comment: Maybe a minimal demo on jsfiddle.net would help.